Is there a way to stop new notifications from replacing old ones on android using capacitor/push-notifications and firebase?
I'm currently trying to replace pushwoosh with capacitor/push-notifications. I know that pushwoosh has a method of correcting this problem by using setMultiNotificationMode, but is there a way to do the same thing with capacitor? Notifications are being delivered to my device, but old ones get replaced by the new ones instead of stacking.
I've followed all of the steps in the documentation for setup and I've tried creating a specific channel using PushNotifications.createChannel, adding a group name and changing the notification ID within the pushNotificationReceived listener with no luck. Is there a functionality that I'm not implementing?
